# ASP.NET and ASP NET MVC applications integration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two applications. One of them using asp.net 2.0. The second is written using asp.net mvc 3. 
Objective is to integrate these applications. Data exchange between applications is not a problem and it works perfect. Problem is to make two sites to look and work like one (from customers point of view). These applications are running on the same iis server and asp.net 2.0 app is an application in virtual directory of mvc application.

I have tried iframes inside views, but there are session issues in asp.net 2.0 application. I use FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie() to make asp.net 2.0 app do not ask credentials, but it works unstable.

What are the best practices of integration such different applications?
How to make asp.net 2.0 application to not ask credentials in an iframe every ~5minutes?

Thanks

Comment: Suggestion, upgrade the 2.0 webform application to run on the .net 4.0 framework. It'll make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I would recommend moving the aspx pages into the MVC application. You can happily put MVC and aspx together in a single application while you migrate the features into the MVC application.

Comment: some example URLs probably would have been helpful. A quick Google search turned up this which covers adding MVC to a reguar ASP.NET project as well as the reverse, ASP.NET Project to MVC: http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-aspnet-webforms-and-aspnet-mvc  and then there is this one http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I do have hybrid implementation of ASP NET MVC and web forms. **They all work fine side-by-side no problem at all.**

My suggestion is to move your web form from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0 (this should normally be painless as everything ) and let them run in the same application.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the best practices of integration such different
>   applications?

In my current job, we move aspx page to the mvc project.So in that case, you have only one project to work on.
If you still insist 2 seperate projects, then I think it just makes your 2 project tight-coupling with each other.

> How to make asp.net 2.0 application to not ask credentials in an
>   iframe every ~5minutes?

One way I can think about is

```
   <location path="Public">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```